# phpmyadmin n:m relation, and CASCADE DELETE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a problem with n:m relation in my database.

I try

```
DELETE FROM `projekty_zadania` WHERE id=1
```

When i delete `id=1` in `projekty_zadania` then in  `todo`  i only have `id=2`  but in `zadania` i have all rows but i need to have only `id_zadania=30`.

How delete it cascade when i delete all id=1 ??

MY TABLES:

zadania:

```
PK id_zadania
     10
     20
     30
```

todo:

```
PK id
   1
   2
```

projekty_zadania  ( this tables are connect the (zadania table and todo table) )

```
PK id_zadania_projekty | FK id  | FK id_zadania
1                      |  1     |  10
2                      |  1     |  20
3                      |  2     |  30
```

---

SCREENS FROM MY PHPMYADMIN:

[zadania](http://www.fotosik.pl/pokaz_obrazek/pelny/81ffd22a5a28d5bb.html)

[projekty_zadania](http://zapodaj.net/88cf24acbf848.png.html)

Comment: There is no `projekty` table.

Comment: sorry my fault zadania =  todo                                                 . Barmar look at 2 link

Comment: As explained in the duplicate question, you can't cascade deletes this way automatically. Deletions only cascade from the referenced table to the referencing one, not the other way.

Comment: How can i delete this "zadania" id=20,30  when i delete todo id =1  ?

Comment: Read the duplicate question.